# pinhole in projector screen

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Consider a conventional slide projector projecting a properly focussed static image from a photographic slide onto a conventional screen, with a second screen placed a short distance behind that one. If there's a small hole in the front screen (that is, the one the slide's projected onto), what will show on the back screen? The full image? An expanded version (inverted or not) of the portion of the image over the hole? Something else?

**Edit:**
If anyone's interested, I did the experiment. I tried holes at several points on the screen, but got the same result in each case: the full image. Out of curiosity I also tried putting a hole in the second screen, and putting a third screen behind it. Once again I got a complete image, though it was very dim.

Answer (score 1):

Only the light intended for that "pixel" hits the spot with the hole in it, so only that pixel's light will make it through the hole and produce a spot on the second screen. The spot will have the same amount of light and color as that "pixel". The size of the spot is proportional to the size of the objective lens times the ratio of distance between the screens to the distance from the first screen to the lens. For example, if the distance between the two screens is the same as the distance from the first screen to the projector, then the size of the spot will be the size of the lens.

Comment: That was my first thought, too, but thinking about it a little more has me doubting it. If you look through the hole from the back of the screen toward the projector you can see the whole slide, which implies that the whole image is present at the hole. Also, isn't this just how pinhole cameras work?

Comment: Actually if you look through the hole all you'll see is the objective lens of the projector and, if the ambient light is bright enough, the table that the projector is sitting on, etc. So yes, its a pinhole camera. I didn't mention that the image projected onto the second screen could, in theory, include the other things in the room because chances are the room lights would not be bright enough for you to make them out compared with the light from the projector, and also they weren't part of the question.